# Create local variables programmatically from a dictionary in Julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Consider the following function:

```
function func(vars::Dict{Symbol, Any})

end
```

I want to create local variables in a `func`'s scope,
where:
variable names are each the key of the `vars` and
variable values are values in a `vars` corresponding to the given key.

I am aware that I could use `eval()` in something like:

```
for (k, v) in vars
    eval(:($k = $v))
end
```

However, that will define variables in the global scope, which has performance repercussions and might override existing global variables.

P.S. I will add a context in case you have suggestions that are drastically different than the approach I am going for. I am implementing a wrapper around the [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl) allowing the users to dynamically create optimization models with arbitrary constraint expressions. Since the constraint expressions are defined using symbols, and `JuMP` requires those symbols to be defined in the current scope, I want the user to provide those symbols and their values in a dictionary to the function. Defining the symbols globally would be cumbersome as the user should ideally be able to run the function multiple times with the same constraint expressions (i.e. same symbols) but different values.

Comment: you should [escape](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene) the expression by `esc(:($k = $v))`

Comment: @GnimucK. But that will still not solve the issue of declaring variables in a global scope.

Comment: hmm... indeed, that won't work. is it possible to build this wrapper in a module?  `eval` will generate variables in the module scope.

Comment: You cannot do this by design. I'm fairly certain that JuMP has APIs for doing this without needing to mess around with local scopes.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/axwQqFeIlCQ

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/j3GeOUK59fA

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I'm not a metaprogramming expert!

I **think** you could do something like this, not with generic functions, but with either a macro or a generated function instead.

Based on this:

```rb
julia> macro bar(dict)
           dump(dict, 10)
       end

julia> @bar Dict(:foo => "foo", :bar => "bar", :baz => "baz");
Expr 
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array(Any,(4,))
    1: Symbol Dict
    2: Expr 
      head: Symbol =>
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Expr 
          head: Symbol quote
          args: Array(Any,(1,))
            1: Symbol foo
          typ: Any
        2: ASCIIString "foo"
      typ: Any
    3: Expr 
      head: Symbol =>
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Expr 
          head: Symbol quote
          args: Array(Any,(1,))
            1: Symbol bar
          typ: Any
        2: ASCIIString "bar"
      typ: Any
    4: Expr
      head: Symbol =>
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Expr
          head: Symbol quote
          args: Array(Any,(1,))
            1: Symbol baz
          typ: Any
        2: ASCIIString "baz"
      typ: Any
  typ: Any
```

I was able to do something like this, it could do more error checking and also *generic macros* would make this easier (at least for error checking) in the development branch:

```rb
julia> macro foo(dict)
           blk = Expr(:block)
           if dict.head == :call && dict.args[1] == :Dict
               for arg in dict.args[2:end]
                   sym = arg.args[1].args[1]
                   val = arg.args[2]
                   push!(blk.args, esc(:($sym = $val)))
               end
           else
               error("Need a Dict{Symbol, Any}")
           end
           blk
       end

julia> @foo Dict(:foo => "foo", :bar => "bar", :baz => "baz");

julia> @show foo bar baz;
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
baz = "baz"

julia> let    # local scope
           @foo Dict(:foo => "foo", :bar => "bar", :baz => "baz")
           @show foo bar baz
       end;
foo = "foo"
bar = "bar"
baz = "baz"
```

Notice you can't create a dict varible and then pass it to the `@foo` macro (again [generic macros](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/14563) could make this easier as there could be a method for `Symbol` also and dispatch an error?):

```rb
julia> dict = Dict(:foo => "foo", :bar => "bar", :baz => "baz");

julia> @foo dict
ERROR: type Symbol has no field head
```

At this point something like:

```rb
@foo a 1 b 2 c 3
```

or

```rb
@foo :a=>1 :b=>2 :c=>3
```

Would be better IMHO.

I would appreciate a lot if someone explains me why this is not optimal! This *answer* should've been a comment, but it's lots of code.

I'll try to implement something similar with generic macros and generated functions and update the post.